# React Hook "useAuthState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a code watching this video from Fireship.io (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQyrwxMPm88&t=204s&ab_channel=Fireship) to build a chatapp using Firestore and using Google Auth in Firebase. I am getting the following error. I know that the video is a bit outdated so please help me out with this one!!

Error Message:
[eslint]
src\App.js
Line 26:16:  React Hook "useAuthState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Error is based on usage of Firebase in Node JS due to version compatibility issues.

Full Code:

```html
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import {useCollectionData} from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
// import {signInAnonymously} from 'firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaCpaZUFe6R2B-l_sTcLLAVt8OlGQ",
  authDomain: "chatapp-9.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "chatapp-09",
  storageBucket: "chatapp-a78ppspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "447574386",
  appId: "1:447083574386b65c8df29c31b067eeb",
  measurementId: "G-98NRKDY"
});

// Initialize Firebase
const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <section>
          {user ? <Chatroom /> : <SignIn />}
        </section>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

function SignIn() {
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
  );
}

function SignOut() {
  return auth.currentUser && (
    <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  )
}

function ChatRoom() {}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you paste the code?

Comment: hi @AvetikNersisyan I have updated the code in the question above. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think the error is very clear... You can't use `useAuthState` or any other hook outside a functional component or custom hook.

Comment: @ivanatias am new to react so can you provide some descriptive solution, this one is really bugging me. Any link to docs or resource will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the video, you should place your `useAuthState` hook inside the `App` component. You cannot use hooks outside of your components. See the [React Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) docs for more information.

```js
function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new to this react stuff so the terminology doesn't really hit in yet. Thanks for your help. It works!!